# EXCEL VBA - Data Iteration and Row Wise Function application

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble doing a row wise function application -

Say I have a formula that is a series that can be summarized as:

```
preformance = ( 1 - (Part1(IdealRate)*Part1(PiecesProduced)) ) + ( 1 - (Part2(IdealRate)*Part2(PiecesProduced)) ) + ...etc
```

If I have an excel spreadsheet in similar style to this -

[image: Excel Example]

How would I send the values from each row to a larger array to be summed - So essentially this is the workflow.

```
#Pseudo Begin#

For Each Row in Rows
(1 -(Part(IdealRate)*Part(PiecesProduced))) -> Send to Array
Next Row
```

When iteration has reached the ending range

```
Array.Value = Sum(AllValuesInArray)
```

I have tried creating ranges for each column needed then creating an array that has the ranges placed within - I have not tried anything beyond this point as I have no idea how to start

Any help would be appreciated ! Thanks

## Edit# Here is an attempt at it

```
Dim GoodQty As Range
Dim PreformanceArray() As Single
Dim Iterator As Long
Set GoodQty = Worksheets("HondaOEE").Range(.Cells(3, 4), .Cells(LastRowH, 4))
Dim RangeLength As Long
RangeLength = Worksheets("HondaOEE").UsedRange.Rows.Count
Dim PValue As Double
ReDim PreformanceArray(1 To 1) As Single

For Iterator = 3 To RangeLength
    PValue = Application.SumProduct(1 - (.Cells(Iterator, 8) * (.Cells(Iterator, 4) + .Cells(Iterator, 5) + .Cells(Iterator, 6))))
    PreformanceArray(UBound(PreformanceArray)) = PValue
    ReDim Preserve PreformanceArray(UBound(PreformanceArray) + 1) As Single
Next Iterator
```

Comment: Would you be open to doing this without VBA?

Comment: @GregViers Through an excel worksheet function ?? Potentially if it still accomplished the same task - the range of the worksheet is dynamic so that is why I am trying to accomplish this through VBA

Comment: `sumproduct` may do what you want. I could write something here but I don't understand your requirement well enough. Is IdealRate column E and PiecesProduced column B?

Comment: @GregViers - Thanks for the help, to answer your question - This is just an example sheet the actual columns are different but I am looking for more a theoretical solution to my problem.

I am looking to send values from some row in some columns to a function then pass that value to an array - then repeat with the next row - After all rows have been indexed through - take the values that are stored in the array and then sum them

Answer (score 0):

You can manage these sorts of complex aggregations using `sumproduct`. This powerful function makes calculations for a range of cells then sums them. In your example above, the formula would be:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(1-$E$2:$E$11*$B$2:$B$11)
```

Comment: Ill try to implement this - Thanks a lot!

Comment: I wasnt able to implement it, I updated my original question with an attempt of mine

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim PreformanceArray() As Double
Dim Iterator As Long
Dim RangeLength As Long
RangeLength = Worksheets("HondaOEE").UsedRange.Rows.Count
RangeLength = RangeLength - 1
Dim PValue As Double
ReDim PreformanceArray(1 To 1) As Double

For Iterator = 3 To RangeLength
    PValue = (1 / .Cells(Iterator, 8) * (.Cells(Iterator, 4) + .Cells(Iterator, 5) + .Cells(Iterator, 6)))
    PreformanceArray(UBound(PreformanceArray)) = PValue
    ReDim Preserve PreformanceArray(1 To UBound(PreformanceArray) + 1) As Double
Next Iterator
```

Here is the correct code that allowed me to do what I needed.